# PopUp dialog onClickListener from fragment - Java Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a fragment within my activity_main. This fragment contains a button (ViewButton). When i press this button I would like for it to bring up a pop Up dialog. 
I have the following code below, the issue is that i get two errors which i dont seem to understand very well: 
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
getLayoutInflater();

They are both coming up as undefined. My guess is that i need to put 'view' or 'this' somewhere, or extend the Activity? But i cant understand exactly the problem.

public class CurrentFragment extends Fragment {

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_fragment, container, false);


    Button ViewButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.ViewButton);

        ViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
          {
          public void onClick(View view)



                //public void ShowPUDialog() 
                {

            AlertDialog.Builder PUHelpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            PUHelpBuilder.setTitle("Enter Pick Up Address");

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View DialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pudialog, null);
            PUHelpBuilder.setView(DialogLayout);

            PUHelpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override   
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                 {

                 }
            });


            AlertDialog helpDialog = PUHelpBuilder.create();
            helpDialog.show();

                }     

          });   

    }


return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try changing your context to AlertDialog.Builder PUHelpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())?

Comment: That works for the AlertDialog Builder. How about the layout inflater?

Comment: @user3247335 same `getActivity().getLayoutInfalter()`

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple. Could someone explain how activities are extended and implented?

Comment: I tried to explain in my edit. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `getActivity()` or `v.getContext()` instead of `this`. Since you are inside of an `OnClickListener` (Anonymous inner class) `this` refers to the `OnClickListener` instead of the proper `Context`. Try something like

```
AlertDialog.Builder PUHelpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
```

You need a `Context` for `getLayoutInflater()` also since it is an `Activity` method so try the same thing

```
v.getContext().getLayoutInflater();
```

**Edit**

Look at the [Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)...it `extends Context` which means it has it's own `Context` and is why you can use `this` when inside of an `Acitivity` method. But as I said, in your `onClick()` you are actually inside of an anonymous inner-class so `this` no longer refers to the `Activity Context`.